# SQL for GA sessions (from BigQuery) with pages containing event within certain time frame

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Trying to optimize a SQL query to find GA sessions containing pages where a "conversion" event occurs within 15 days. If page, e.g., "/example/product", contains a GA event "conversion" on June 15 then I want to count all sessions from June 1-15 that hit that page, regardless of whether or not those sessions contained a conversion event.

Is there a better way than joining to get this data? Perhaps with windowing?

I have a working query but it runs increasingly slowly when querying tables over longer time ranges and eventually fails. I've first selected only sessions with pages where a conversion happened over the entire time range of the query, then joined to those same pages with the date of conversion, then finally selected only the sessions where the date_diff between the conversion date and session date is between 0 and 15.

```
SELECT
  date,
  COUNT (DISTINCT sessionId) AS sessions
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    CONCAT(CAST(visitId AS STRING),fullVisitorId) AS sessionId,
    hits.page.pagePath AS pagepath
  FROM
    `[dataset].ga_sessions_201906*` t,
    t.hits hits
  WHERE
    hits.page.pagePath IN (
    SELECT
      DISTINCT(hits.page.pagePath) AS pagepath
    FROM
      `[dataset].ga_sessions_201906*` t,
      t.hits hits
    WHERE
      REGEXP_CONTAINS( hits.eventInfo.eventAction, r'(?i)conversion'))
  GROUP BY
    date,
    visitId,
    fullVisitorId,
    pagepath)
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT(hits.page.pagePath) AS pagepath,
    date AS conversionDate
  FROM
    `[dataset].ga_sessions_201906*` t,
    t.hits hits
  WHERE
    REGEXP_CONTAINS( hits.eventInfo.eventAction, r'(?i)conversion')
  ORDER BY
    pagepath,
    conversionDate)
USING
  (pagepath)
WHERE
  DATE_DIFF(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',
      conversionDate),PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',
      date), DAY) BETWEEN 0 AND 15
GROUP BY
  date
ORDER BY
  date
```

It does produce expected results over shorter time periods but in testing over longer periods the query failed with the following message: "The service is currently unavailable."

Comment: I recommend deleting your 'ORDER BY' in your inner subquery.  It is an unnecessary computation that frequently leads to resource errors when datasets get big.

Comment: What do you mean with "testing over longer periods?" As per my understanding, you are querying partitioned tables for 30 days period (ga_sessions_201906*), where the obtained data are the ones occurred within 15 days period over the defined month, e.g., if the event occurred on June 1st, only the "conversion" events for 1 day will be displayed, therefore, are you planning to query data outside the defined date?

Thanks in advance.